# How to find exceptions thrown by OpenReadAsync method

Tags: c#, windows-8, exception, windows-store-apps

Consider the following code:

```
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
    using (DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(stream))
    {
        uint length = (uint)stream.Size;
        await dataReader.LoadAsync(length);
        txtbox.Text = dataReader.ReadString(length);
    }
}
```

`storageFile.OpenReadAsync` may throw exception, `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` is one possible exception type. MSDN topic `StorageFile.OpenReadAsync` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.openreadasync doesn't contain list of exception types thrown by this method. How can I find this information from documentation? I can catch an `Exception` type, but this is poor programming practice.

Comment: Have you tried disassembling the .dll?

Comment: StorageFile is part of Windows Runtime. Don't think that it will be possible to disassemble windows runtime to find the exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where it is impossible to find all list of exceptions I usually use approach from VS SDK [ErrorHandler.IsCriticalException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.errorhandler.iscriticalexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    if (ErrorHandler.IsCriticalException(e))
    {
        throw;
    }

    // log it or show something to user
}
```

You can decompile the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0.dll` to find the list of exceptions, which ErrorHandler defines as Critical:

- StackOverflowException
- AccessViolationException
- AppDomainUnloadedException
- BadImageFormatException
- DivideByZeroException

In the case of Windows Runtime I think that it will be good also to verify some of the [HResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult.aspx) values in Exception, like E_OUTOFMEMORY, E_ABORT, E_FAIL, and maybe something else.

Also I found that [BugSense](https://www.bugsense.com/) is awesome help for logging exceptions. I use it not only for unhandled exception, but also for situations like this, where I have no idea what this method can throw. It allows to send custom logging (including exceptions) with `BugSenseHandler.Instance.LogException`, so I just collect information about different kind of exceptions (including exceptions with some unexpected HResult) and make some improvements for my app in each release.

Comment: Using `ErrorHandler.IsCriticalException` is a good idea. This reduces the shame of using `catch(Exception)`. I hope that Microsoft will improve their documentation for Windows Store. Thanks.